# Is there a way to set a custom size for a JPanel in IntelliJ IDEA without using code?

Tags: java, swing

I tried changing the Layout Manager, but still couldn't set the desired size. In some cases, it allowed me to change only the width, but not the height.

## Form:

## [image: form]
Goal:

[image: I'm trying to create something like this.]

Here is the code just in case if needed.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Second {
    private JPanel panel1;
    public Second() {
        
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Second Form");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new Second().getPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. In fact, usually it is best to avoid setting sizes or preferred sizes and instead letting the layout managers do it for you. In this case, please tell and show what type of GUI you are trying to create, what the end product should look like.

Comment: I added a picture of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You'll probably (for the main part) be looking at a `JTable` with each rendered cell being a `JPanel` with its components and image laid out with a `BoxLayout`

Comment: Consider creating several JPanels and then nesting layouts. The Menu items JPanel could use a BorderLayout with a button JPanel at the bottom that uses either FlowLayout or GridLayout with 1 row, 0 columns (which means a variable number of columns) and some horizontal gap value. It would be placed in the menuItemsPanel at the BorderLayout.PAGE_END location.

Comment: The individual menu cards could use a BoxLayout, and they could be placed in a menu grid JPanel that uses GridLayout and that implements the Scrollable interface so that it sizes a  scroll pane's viewport correctly. Those all would likely be placed into the viewport of a JScrollPane.

Comment: The right JPanel could use a BorderLayout that holds a JList within a JScrollPane in the CENTER position, and a GridLayout using JPanelin the PAGE_END position. The main JPanel that holds everything could use either a BorderLayout or a BoxLayout...

Comment: ... but there are many many ways to skin this fish.

Comment: Do you need a solution that uses the form builder?  For most of us, suggesting code is easier than suggesting form builder usage.